# PHP making input from web form case insensitive?

Tags: php, parsing, forms, case-insensitive

So I have some code here that takes user input from a standard web form:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $searchsport = stripslashes($_POST['sport']);
    $sportarray = array(
        "Football" => "Fb01",
        "Cricket" => "ck32",
        "Tennis" => "Tn43",
    );
    if (isset($sportarray[$searchsport])) {
        header("Location: " . $sportarray[$searchsport] . ".html");
    die;
}
```

How would I go about modifying this (I think the word is parsing?) to make it case **in**sensitive? For example, I type in "fOoTbAlL" and PHP will direct me to Fb01.html normally.

Note that the code is just an example. The string entered by the user can contain more than one word, say "Crazy aWesOme HarpOOn-Fishing", and it would still work if the array element "Crazy Awesome Harpoon-Fishing" (take note of the capital `F` before the dash).

Comment: Forgot to add that I'm looking for minimal changes to the code (no changes to the array).

Comment: There are some solutions that do this read them

Comment: Why are you using get_magic_quotes_gpc? Don't use it...never...anyway i don't think that in this case you need to use stripslashes

Comment: It's just to take out the apostrophes say the user types in Joe's, it will match Joe's in the array instead of Joe\'s. Unfortunately I have to add it in, my web host sets it as default.

Comment: but what is the error that you get with stripslashes?

Comment: Nevermind, as I've explained below (sorry to keep you jumping all over the place) there isn't anything wrong with stripslashes, found this out by chucking a whole bunch of echos.

Comment: If the problem is with ucfirst then you should use ucwords instead

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Would it include words with dashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$searchsport = strtolower($_POST['sport']);
$sportarray = array(
    "football" => "Fb01",
    "cricket" => "ck32",
    "tennis" => "Tn43",
);
if (isset($sportarray[$searchsport])){
    header("Location: " . $sportarray[$searchsport] . ".html");
    die;
}
```

In this way the search string and the array keys are both lowercase and you can do a case insensitive comparison.

If you want to preserve the case of the `$sportarray` keys you can do:

```
$searchsport = ucfirst(strtolower($_POST['sport']));
$sportarray = array(
    "Football" => "Fb01",
    "Cricket" => "ck32",
    "Tennis" => "Tn43",
);
if (isset($sportarray[$searchsport])){
    header("Location: " . $sportarray[$searchsport] . ".html");
    die;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Just wondering if I used stripslashes with this properly:
$searchitem = ucfirst(strtolower(stripslashes($_POST["item"])));? I've tried your code everything works fine except for the stripslashes.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand now why it isn't working. There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is the ucfirst function which only converts the first word. If I had Lawn Bowls in my array it will not match. Instead when I type lawn bowls, it would be Lawn bowls. Am I correct?

Comment: Then you can use ucwords instead of ucfirst

Comment: Does ucwords recognise "a-word-like-this" as 4 words or just 1?

Comment: I don't know test it but you can replace every - with a space if you want

Answer (score 2):

I would use a string function, [`strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/strtolower).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to make everything lowercase to make your comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your code like this:

```
// Searches for values in case-insensitive manner
function in_arrayi($needle, $haystack) {
    return in_array(strtolower($needle), array_map('strtolower', $haystack));
}

$searchsport = $_POST['sport'];
$sportarray = array(
    "Football" => "Fb01",
    "Cricket" => "ck32",
    "Tennis" => "Tn43",
);

if(in_arrayi($searchsport, $sportarray)){
    header("Location: " . $sportarray[$searchsport] . ".html");
    die;
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with this approach is that you're calling strtolower four times rather than just one.

Comment: @King: I think it is not, please see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#89256

Comment: You are not converting to lower case the variable in the string that you pass into the header function so it won't match

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work but maybe i'm using a different version of php

Comment: 5.2.something...It doesn't return true to the condition i don't know why

Comment: No warning message, no output at all. Can you incorporate the stripslashes like we did before also?

Comment: @Haskella: Try with others' answers with `strtolower`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$searchsport = $_POST['sport'];
$sportarray = array(
"Football" => "Fb01",
"Cricket" => "ck32",
"Tennis" => "Tn43",
);
if(isset($sportarray[ucfirst(strtolower($searchsport]))])){
    header("Location: ".$sportarray[$searchsport].".html");
    die;
}
?>
```

notice `ucfirst(strtolower($searchsport]))`?

LE: added ucfirst

Comment: This will never match as the items in `$sportarray` aren't lowercase!

Comment: This will never match, unless you make your array keys lower case too.  </nitpick>

Comment: Same comment I made for mck89, this will not work if the string entered contains 2 or more words.